# Claim based authentication from PHP to Windows?

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap, claims-based-identity

i work at a company where all my web-applications connect to the LDAP-Directories or the AD for Authentication and/or Authorisation purposes. Generally this works quite well. Nowadays though - especially due to the latest introdution to SP2010 - people are looking forward to single sign ons and don't wanna re-login.

So my Question:

Is there any way to make PHP Claim the Authentication from Windows? I mean sure SharePoint does it with WIF on IIS - maybe theres a way PHP is as awesome :P

My quick google didnt bring up any great results, so my hopes aren't up too high, but i figured asking you guys might be worth a shot. Thanks in advance - happy new year!

Comment: Are you looking for SSO support in PHP with the SSO provider being a AD or SP? Or, are you looking to do LDAP or AD authentication with PHP?

Comment: The first one, i guess. I do LDAP/AD Authentication right now, though since using SharePoint, people dont want to login, but rather BE logged in :) So i wanna know if that's possible with PHP

Comment: Perhaps this will be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242669/sharepoint-sso-with-a-php-application-on-a-different-server

Comment: Thanks for this, it's actually of some use, but i'm rather looking for a sharepoint-free solution. Is there something like that, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way to implement this in pure PHP. I've had the exact same task and done it, but the whole solution involves **raw** HTTP/1.1, NTLM and SMB (Windows share) over TCP/UDP/NetBIOS - at the least. Each of those alone is complicated enough and PHP hasn't got any extensions to help with them.

There is an "Apache way" though:

- mod_auth_sspi (if you're running on Windows)
- mod_auth_ntlm (I think this only works with Apache <= 1.3)
- libapache2-authenntlm-perl (there are reports that this one causes the web server to hang after receiving a large number of requests)
- mod_auth_kerb (haven't used this one, but NTLM is replaced by a Microsoft implementation of KerberosV5 and it's the most modern solution available; however, it requires additional server configuration)

Comment: Thank you for the information, certainly will look into it. Sounds a little 'out of league' now, given the time i can invest, but that's certainly a challenge for the future so, thank you!