# ntml message encrypt from client issue

Tags: php, ntlm, ntlmv2

last two days I was searching for NTLM library for php. One of our service uses Auhorization based on NTLM protocol. I want to integrate/automate process from another service. In other words I need to crypt and send type 3 message to authenticate, but can't do.
Can anyone advice me, what to do?

**EDIT**

Problem is that I have php script, which wants to update destination source [NTLM based] with some content. It need to login and update contents. If you see browser`s console log [developer bar], you will see that it's made in 3 steps [handshakes]
here is doc, I found
http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html

Desire is: I want to learn how to correctly make headers[encode] to login with provided credentials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Claim based authentication from PHP to Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709031/claim-based-authentication-from-php-to-windows)

Comment: No, it's not the case.

Comment: I was actually trying to help you with that, but there are at least 3 other valid reasons to close the question ... it's too broad, shows barely any research effort and the only viable type of an answer (suggesting a tool/library/other off-site material) is not allowed around here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually curl has built in functionality

```
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM
CURLOPT_USERPWD, domain\\username:password
```

That's it